# Rails nokogiri XML create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

In ruby on rails i use Nokogiri to create XML files. Now I want to create a XML line like this:

```
<mis:actions param="-900" accuracy="1" cameraIndex="0" payloadType="0" payloadIndex="0">GimbalPitch</mis:actions>
```

I thought the code has to look like this (1):

```
xml['mis'].actions('param' => "-900", "accuracy" => "1", "cameraIndex" => "0", "payloadType" => "0", "payloadIndex" => "0") 'GimbalPitch'
```

or (2)

```
xml['mis'].actions('param' => "-900", "accuracy" => "1", "cameraIndex" => "0", "payloadType" => "0", "payloadIndex" => "0") do 
'GimbalPitch'
end
```

But (1) is not working at all and (2) looks like this:

```
<mis:actions param="-900" accuracy="1" cameraIndex="0" payloadType="0" payloadIndex="0">
```

So in (2) i miss the part ...`GimbalPitch</mis:actions>` at the end.

Thanks, Andreas